# Generate new uuidv4 in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uuid

I have a react app that generates a uuidv4 to store in a firestore doc when a user submits a comments through a button.

```
const [id, setID] = useState(uuidv4());

  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = () => {
      db.collection("Videos")
      .doc(video.id)
      .collection("comments")
      .doc(id)
      .set({
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        comment: comment,
        id: id,
        channelName: currentUser.displayName,
        email: currentUser.email,
      });
  }
```

This works great, but if a users submits two comments before refreshing, the uuidv4 does not change and instead of adding another comment, the comments submitted beforehand is overwritten. How can I have the uuidv4 regenerated at the end of  "const handleSubmit"?

Comment: Set a new id after your firestore call with `setID(uuidv4())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set new id inside the function,

Add this line inside the handleSubmit function

```
setID(uuidv4())
```

The final handleSubmit function looks like

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
      setID(uuidv4());
      db.collection("Videos")
      .doc(video.id)
      .collection("comments")
      .doc(id)
      .set({
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        comment: comment,
        id: id,
        channelName: currentUser.displayName,
        email: currentUser.email,
      });
  }
```